# JAVA FileNotFound when writing file to existing folder

Tags: java, blob, inputstream, filenotfoundexception, fileoutputstream

I have a process where I sync a folder with files that is on a database. There is just below 50000 files that sync. Some of the files sync perfectly; However on one file I receive a File Not Found Exception. I do check if the parent directory exists and I create it if not.

The File writing code is as follows:

```
for(Map<String,Object> file: fileList)
{
    createDirectory(file); //Creates the directory

    Blob outBlob = (Blob)file.get("fileData");

    InputStream is = outBlob.getBinaryStream();
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream((String)file.get("path"));

    int b = 0;  
    while ((b = is.read()) != -1)  
    {  
        fos.write(b);   
    }  

    fos.flush();
    fos.close();
}
```

And the createDirectory method:

```
public static void createDirectory(Map<String,Object> file) throws IOException
{

    // Create parent directory - If directory does not exist
    File directory = new File(file.get("parent"));

    if (!directory.exists()) 
    {     
        System.out.println("Parent Directory does not exist, creating ...");
        // ...create it
        if (!directory.mkdirs()) 
        {   
           System.out.println("Parent Directory creation failed ..."); 
        }
    }
}
```

This is the line that gives a FileNotFoundException

```
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream((String)file.get("path"));
```

The parent directory is C:\temp\

I do have permissions on the above folder.

The createDirectory method does not log anything to the console as the directory does exist.

I have searched for a few days and cannot see why this one file will fail while the others succeed.
Any help would be appreciated.

The above code has been trimmed down and variable names changed. Due to security reasons I am not allowed to give the stack trace. I have tried to duplicate the error but had no luck in doeing so.

PS this is my first time asking on stackoverflow, please forgive me if I broke some standards rule.

Regards,

Comment: could you please give more information like what do u provide as a Object in Map<String,Object>..

Comment: You need to give us the actual name of the file that gives you this error, i.e. the string returned by `file.get("path")`.  Is it valid? Is it the same as an already existing directory?  This is one case where the code is less important than the exact context in which it is run.

Comment: Thank you. I was worried that this was a code issue that I kept missing. In case of the file that fails the Map<String,Object> file contains: "parent":"C:\\temp\\","fileData":(File Bytes),"path":"C:\\temp\\PosNewBussinessDocument.PDF"

Comment: Normally a `FileNotFoundException` has a message. What does it say?

Comment: After the File Not Found Exception the stack trace just says No such file or directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a closer look at my log Files and I found that there was some strange white space character in front of the file name. I tried to replicate this character but was not able to do so. String.trim() will solved this issue when saving and using the file names.

Regards,